# How do I find collaborators to help build a new world?

Tags: worldbuilding-resources

I'm new to worldbuilding, so it would be good to find more experienced people who can help me build my first world. I know this isn't a discussion forum, so where would I go to find the support that I'm seeking?

Comment: You could do worse than to start by reading our [worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143606/a-list-of-worldbuilding-resources) post, then ask a (worldbuilding) question or two here, there are many who'll be happy to help. You can (when you have sufficient reputation (it might be 20 or 50 or 100, someone'll chime-in and say)) start a chat room. Although I've forgotten how, it should be in the [help]. Welcome to worldbuilding.

Comment: @ARogueAnt.
Thank you, I'll check it out.

Comment: Got it, you can participate in chat at 20 points (you're halfway there at the time of this comment), and create your own chat rooms at 100 rep points. It's in the list of [privileges](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Here's a complete list of [Worldbuilding chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=worldbuilding.stackexchange.com), "The Factory Floor" being the main one (an allusion to Magrathea from THHGTTG.), but there's plenty of active ones on particular topics.

Comment: How is this question considered off-topic? How would it be worded to be considered on-topic?
It's somewhat an academic point because my question has been answered to my satisfaction.
Thank you @ARogueAnt.

Comment: It would have been on-topic on [meta-worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com) because it's a general inquiry for help, on this particular platform we answer specific questions about the creation of the worlds themselves, geography, weather patterns, society, creature design etc..

Comment: @ARogueAnt.
OK thanks for the clarification.